# LibGDX: Cannot load a json file from assets folder

Tags: java, json, gwt, libgdx, filehandle

I have a json file with data for all the tiles in my game that I store in the assets folder. I try to access and parse it using `TileList dataList = json.fromJson(TileList.class, Gdx.file.internal("map-elements/tiles/tiles.json"))`. This works fine for the desktop version but on the html version, after converting with gwt, I get these errors:

```
GwtApplication: exception: Error reading file: map-elements/tiles/tiles.json
Error reading file: map-elements/tiles/tiles.json
Couldn't find Type for class 'net.vediogames.archipelo.world.tiles.TileList'
```

TileList is a simple object that contains an array of TileData which can then be converted into Tile objects. I did it this way to make the json parsing easy.

Comment: I found this thread, it may have the solution. Will try it once I get home. http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9083

Comment: I fixed it. I did this instead: `TileList dataList = json.fromJson(TileList.class, Gdx.file.internal("map-elements/tiles/tiles.json").readString())`. I still get the `Couldn't find Type for class 'net.vediogames.archipelo.world.tiles.TileList'` error. But I think it's for a whole other reason altogether.

Comment: Hello - if you fix the issue you should add it as answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the json error is simple. Instead of passing the FileHandle into the json parser, pass the string from the file like this:

```
TileList dataList = json.fromJson(TileList.class, Gdx.file.internal("map-elements/tiles/tiles.json").readString());
```

In the end, all I needed to do to solve that issue is add `.readString()`. As for the `Couldn't find Type for class 'net.vediogames.archipelo.world.tiles.TileList'` error, I also found a solution but it is more complicated.

JavaScript handles class references differently than Java. So I was not able to use `TileList.class` without first registering it so LibGDX can generate a Reflection. What I needed to do was add this line into my *.gwt.xml files:

`<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="net.vediogames.archipelo.world.tiles.TileList" />`

If you want a full tutorial about how reflection works and how to include packages or exclude, please view the official LibGDX tutorial [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reflection).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution was not working for me, I still got the same error. After some hours of testing I got it to work, using your suggestions and by using the `ClassReflection` instead of referencing the class itself.
Your example:

```
TileList dataList = json.fromJson(TileList.class, Gdx.file.internal("map-elements/tiles/tiles.json").readString());
```

looks in my working code like:

```
TileList dataList = (TileList) json.fromJson(ClassReflection.forName(TileList.class.getName()), Gdx.file.internal("map-elements/tiles/tiles.json").readString());
```

This is quite a pain in the a.. but I'm glad it is finally working now.

Comment: I ended up doing this too. I forgot to post it. Thanks for sharing :)